# Bash: Copy a list of files that contain (lots of) special characters

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix, shell

I'm well aware of how to simply copy a list of files to another location using bash, but the problem is that my list of files contains filenames that contain just about EVERY character that needs to be escaped in bash. There are tons of spaces, !, ",", "'", ?, and just about every other character you could think of that needs to be escaped.

I initially tired going through the text file and escaping all of these characters but it's... exhausting, even with search and replace (however that DOES work) (I tested it with a much smaller list of files.) I also tried adding single quotes in the text file before and after the path, but that doesn't work. I also tried adding single quotes before an after the % after cp, but obviously I have no idea what I'm doing. :) (I do know I'd have to escape single quotes in the text file if I were to somehow surround the file path with single quotes.)

I'm using this command to copy the list of files into another location, but again, it doesn't work with special characters.

```
cat file.txt | xargs -J % cp % ./folderToMoveto/
```

I know that there are other commands that do the same thing without having to pipe anything into xargs, and some answers here say that xargs can do it itself, but I haven't gotten those to work, while the above one does work.

Also, I'm on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU xargs has a `-0` option to allow it to read null-byte delimited data. On Linux, you can do:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file.txt | xargs -0 cp -t /folder/to/move/to
```

Sadly, Apple has taken their legacy Darwin man pages site off-line, so I can't check if there's a MacOS equivalent.

Comment: You can find on-line documentation for MacOS commands at `https://ss64.com/osx/`. From the home page `https://ss64.com/` you can find documentation for a number of scripting environments.

Comment: I mean, honestly the spaces (null byte) aren't really the problem. The problem is the rest of the 20+ characters that need to be escaped. I can fix the space problem with a simple search and replace. I'm looking for a way to add single quotes to the xargs command so I don't have to bother escaping anything but a single quote. (Or am I being stupid here and not understanding your response?)

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do any escaping with this recipe. Can you cut'n'paste your attempts into the question?

Comment: @user2634928 the `-0` in `xargs -0`  make sure that no characters need special treatment, as only `\0` will be taken at end of filename, all the rest will be used as is. `xargs`  does not use the shell and will call `cp` direcly passing it the filename as is with any characters that would have needed special treatment in the shell.

Comment: @glennjackman What would you like me to copy and paste? When I try my original code with a plain text file with a full path on every line, CP will stumble over the spaces initially, then when I escape the spaces, CP will stumble over all of the other bad characters (!, ?, , , ', ", etc.) As for your solution, os X cp does not have the -t option, or anything similar.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I don't understand (sorry.) Yes, tr will replace the new line characters with \0, which xargs will only accept as the "end of a line". But then it'll pass the entire line, full of characters that cp doesn't like to cp, and cp will still stumble over it... right? At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @user2634928 `cp` can handle weird characters just fine; the times you'll run into trouble is when the shell (or something else) processes the filenames before they get to `cp`. `xargs -0` doesn't do *anything* except split based on null bytes, and passes the results of that directly to the command (`cp` in this case). AIUI that's exactly what you want.

Comment: BTW, the version of `cp` that comes with macOS doesn't support the `-t` option, so you need to use `... | xargs -0J% cp % /folder/to/move/to`

Comment: @GordonDavisson OOOoooo.... I thought the problem was with cp. Unfortunately, your solution to get around the no -t option still does not work. cp still can't find the files. https://postimg.cc/image/53mfvuejh/ I guarantee the files are in those locations, mainly because I generated the list using bash itself (and I showed the file info below the command.) (I have a test list file with only 3 files listed in it.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Also yes, I'm well aware that the directories and files are named... poorly. I was in the process of renaming them when I... screwed everything up. This is part of the recovery effort.The list of files I have is a list of files that my previous recovery script couldn't deal with and generated errors. (So basically every file is "problematic".) I generated the list using "find" to find all normal files (not directories) then comparing that list with the list of locations from iTunes itself. So everything not common was deemed "lost" and put in this text file.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Nevermind, your solution works fine. I forgot to remove the single quotes from the file after a previous fix attempt.